# Full screen gvim window manager limitations on Ubuntu

Tags: vim, ubuntu, fullscreen

So I've had this slightly annoying problem when running gvim on Ubuntu. When I enforce full-screen mode I get white bars at the bottom and right of the screen.  (I'm trying to emulate the Mac-vim full screen mode)

(I would have posted an image but I'm a new user and apparently can't do that.)
**Edit** I think this screenshot using Xephyr shows what's happening at a reasonable screen shot size:

[image]

**<sub>*Note that the screenshot only shows a 'small' bar at the right. In reality, at 3328x1152 there is a significant 'panel-like' bar at both the bottom and the right of the screen*</sub>**

I've found very little on Google and nothing on stackoverflow about this, but that might be because I've got the wrong search params, but from what I understand it's to do with the window manager imposing restrictions on the window. If anyone knows a workaround for this I'd greatly appreciate it, I'm using the default Ubuntu window manager.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like what you see is the default GTK background.

Follow [this hint](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Vim#Empty_space_at_the_bottom_of_gvim_windows) to make it the same color as your colorscheme's background. I've used it and it works beautifully.

Answer (score 1):

I usually use console vim in gnome-terminal: it supports a builtin (`F11`) full screen mode that doesn't have this problem.

- I tweaked the terminal profile no hide scrollbars and menubars
- You get font resizing on the fly (<sub><kbd>Ctrl-Shift-`+`</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl-Shift-`-`</kbd></sub>)
- This also gains me `screen` support
- slightly better responsivity
- slightly better support for shell integration (e.g. <kbd>K</kbd> for man pages, backgrounding using <kbd>C-z</kbd>

The only thing missing from this setup is the vim-style X clipboard integration, AFAICT

**Update** screenshot of gvim Version: 2:7.2.330-1ubuntu4 in the same Xehpyr session (running the windowmanager (compiz) and Xephyr from natty, but the 'old' vim-package as chrooted from my old Maverick setup:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the reply- terminal fullscreen works perfectly, but I was after a solution for gvim in a regular gnome window.

Comment: @user975391: yeah I'm looking into it! So far it seems gvim 2:7.2.330-1ubuntu4 did _not_ have the same issue (added screenshot)

Comment: Actually, you can compile vim with X11 integration, so the clipboard works the same as in gvim.